# How verify that page is scrolled up and how verify text is visible on screen in playwright?

Tags: typescript, scroll, playwright, assertion

I need an assertion to check if a page has scrolled to the top and an assertion to check if an element is visible on screen. How to do it in playwright with TypeScript?

```
const isScrolledUp = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return window.pageYOffset === 0;
      });      
      expect(isScrolledUp).toBe(true);

const visibleScreen = page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Some Name' });
await expect(visibleScreen).toBeFocused();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could scroll with the mouse to a very low "sure-to-scroll-to-the-top" y-value and then assure with toBeInViewport()

```js
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('Test @00', async ({page}) => {
    
    // Scrolls to the top of the page
    await page.mouse.wheel(0, -100000000)
    const isScrolledUp = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return window.scrollY === 0;
    });
    expect(isScrolledUp).toBe(true);

    // toBeInViewport checks only the current view
    await expect(page.getByRole('heading', {name: 'Some name'})).toBeInViewport()
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much, and a question as to why this test only works from a terminal. To do the test in 'Test Explorer' I have to change toBe(false)

Comment: By 'Test Explorer', you mean --ui mode, debug mode or something else? I ran the above in UI-mode and it executed as expected.

Comment: using --ui, I get this error:
```
await page.mouse.wheel(0, -100000000)
34
    const isScrolledUp = await page.evaluate(() => {
35
      return window.scrollY === 0;
36
    });
37
    expect(isScrolledUp).toBe(true);
                                    
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: true
Received: false
```

Comment: I have already found what the problem was :) works :D